# maven profile overwrites test resources

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to make maven profiles which would use two difference DBMS. DBMS configs are stored in maven profiles. Web App gets settings from file connection.properties in src/main/resources. There is also a similar file with same title connection.properties in src/test/resources and this file should be uploaded only during test lyfecycle maven. Then spring core uses the DBMS connection settings specified in connection.properties.

I have problem with maven profile which overwrites resources such as src/test/resources/connection.properties on src/main/resources/connection.properties from test directory when test lifecycle maven is running.

```
<profile>
        <id>profile-postgres</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <database.driver_class_name>org.postgresql.Driver</database.driver_class_name>
            <database.url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/bulls_and_cows</database.url>
            <database.username>postgres</database.username>
            <database.password>postgres</database.password>

            <jpa.show_sql>true</jpa.show_sql>
            <jpa.generate_ddl>true</jpa.generate_ddl>
            <jpa.database>POSTGRESQL</jpa.database>
            <jpa.database_platform>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</jpa.database_platform>
            <jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>validate</jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
            <jpa.hibernate.format_sql>false</jpa.hibernate.format_sql>

            <h2.scope>test</h2.scope>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
            <id>profile-h2</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <database.driver_class_name>org.h2.Driver</database.driver_class_name>
                <database.url>jdbc:h2:mem:h2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</database.url>
                <database.username>sa</database.username>
                <database.password>sa</database.password>

                <jpa.show_sql>true</jpa.show_sql>
                <jpa.generate_ddl>true</jpa.generate_ddl>
                <jpa.database>H2</jpa.database>
                <jpa.database_platform>org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</jpa.database_platform>
                <jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>create-drop</jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
                <jpa.hibernate.format_sql>false</jpa.hibernate.format_sql>

                <h2.scope>compile</h2.scope>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

This profile overwrites my connection.properties from src/test/resources on src/main/resources.

connection.properties from src/test/resources

```
database.driver_class_name=org.h2.Driver
database.url=jdbc:h2:mem:h2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
database.username=sa
database.password=sa
```

connection.properties from src/main/resources

```
database.driver_class_name=${database.driver_class_name}
database.url=${database.url}
database.username=${database.username}
database.password=${database.password}
```

I wrote testResources tag in build tag of root pom file and in build tag of profile tag such as

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

But instead connection.properties from src/main/resources was always used in test lifecycle of maven.

My old failed build where I used profiles from https://travis-ci.org/WeDism/BullsAndCows/builds/449051809.

My repo with master branch https://github.com/WeDism/BullsAndCows/blob/master/pom.xml.

My repo with with_profiles_h2_postgres branch https://github.com/WeDism/BullsAndCows/blob/with_profiles_h2_postgres/pom.xml

Profile profile-postgres should be main such as activeByDefault = true

Comment: Why all the complexity? You don't need different profiles for that. For testing the `connection.properties` from the test will override the one from the main already. Why the hack with the additional profiles.

Comment: If I run local app I can choose use embedded DBMS such as h2 if I don't have postgres.

Comment: This allows me to tune the environment more fine.

Comment: Still why all the complexity. You don’t need it, nor should you want it.

Comment: Current case. I don't have DB on my laptop and I can run my app without postgres  using only java without many actions for tune my project.

Comment: Use Spring profiles for that instead of rebuilding the artificact for different environments. The fact that your application requires different configs per environment doesn’t mean you should build new artifacts for different environments. With such an approach you are going live without testing the build artifact (as that differs from the one tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fix this problem I changed property names such as
`<database.driver_class_name>` to `<database.driver_class_name.pom>`.